# Remove empty / null element from List

Tags: java, java-8

Hello i have been trying to remove empty / null  element from List , have tried multiple things . not sure if i am missing something.

```
    public String getString() {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> string1 = getDateResult();
    List<String> string2 = getStringResult();
    List<String> string3 = getNumberResult();
    List<String> string4 = getBookResult();

    result.add(string1);
    result.add(string2);
    result.add(string3);
    result.add(string4);

    // below are the things I already tried doesnt work 
    result.removeIf(List::isEmpty);
    result.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null,""));

    return result;
    }
```

Example Input

2020-08-10 , Hello , , Book1  --> cant remove / delete the empty String.

Comment: You can not add a `List<String>` to a `List<String>`. This code will already fail before the marked lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove null or empty List inside List `List<List<String>>`

```
result.removeIf(list->list==null || list.isEmpty());
```

or if you want to remove null or empty elements from inner lists

```
result.forEach(list->list.removeIf(ele->ele==null || ele.isEmpty()));
```

Comment: result.forEach(list->list.removeIf(ele->ele==null || ele.isBlank())); this doesnt seem to  be correct @deadpool

Comment: What do you mean not correct? Can you show an example with input and output @icecool09

Comment: Could be because `isBlank` is not a part of Java-8.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add one list into another use the `addAll(..)` method.

This assumes that you don't get a `null` back as a result of any method that creates `string1, string1` lists.

```
result.addAll(string1); result.addAll(string2); ...
```

As `result` is a `List<String>`, you can now use the `removeIf` method to remove any invalid strings from you `result`.

If you are open to using Apache utils you can use the `StringUtils.isBlank(str)`

Comment: I used  " Stream.concat(Stream.concat(string1.stream(), string2.stream()), string3.stream(), string4.stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()) "